# Pentaho CCC Line Chart limited to 12 months

Tags: javascript, mdx, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I've made a simple CCC Line Chart with a Date Range input selector. On the X-Axis I have months. The Cube I'm getting the data from is the default Steel Wheels so the Time dimensions has Years Quarters and Months.
The problem is that when I select a interval longer than 12 months the visualization is limited to the first 12 months (there are no repeating month names). How can I overcome this obstacle? I'm figuring that I need to set the X-Axis to visualize Year-Month instead of only Month but I don't know how.

The MDX query to extract the data is:

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Sales] ON COLUMNS,
    {[Time].[${param_start_year}].[${param_start_quarter}].[${param_start_month}]:[Time].[${param_end_year}].[${param_end_quarter}].[${param_end_month}]} ON ROWS
FROM
    [SteelWheelsSales]
```

The javascript function to extract YEAR QUARTER and MONTH from the data selector is:

```
function extract_function(){

dateFrom = Dashboards.getParam('dateFrom');
dateTo = Dashboards.getParam('dateTo');
tmp_date = new Date(dateFrom);
var quarter = ['QTR1','QTR2','QTR3','QTR4'];
var month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

param_start_year = tmp_date.getFullYear();
param_start_quarter = quarter[Math.floor((tmp_date.getMonth()+ 3) / 3)-1];
param_start_month = month[tmp_date.getMonth()];

tmp_date = new Date(dateTo);
param_end_year = tmp_date.getFullYear();
param_end_quarter = quarter[Math.floor((tmp_date.getMonth()+ 3) / 3)-1];
param_end_month = month[tmp_date.getMonth()];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is not so elegant, but working solution:

```
WITH
MEMBER Measures.[Years] as 
Ancestor([Time].Currentmember, [Time].[Years]).Properties("MEMBER_CAPTION")
SELECT
NON EMPTY { Measures.[Years], [Measures].[Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
[Time].[2003].[QTR1].[Jan]:[Time].[2005].[QTR1].[Feb] ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
```

You can use calculated column to manipulate strings for captions